# Explanation with NTLK codes and python calendar

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

Please can someone help me interpret what these codes are saying?

```
df['date'] = df['text'].apply(lambda x:re.findall(r'\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}|\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{2,4}|[A-Z][a-z]+\-\d{1,2}\-\d{4}|[A-Z][a-z]+[,.]? \d{2}[a-z]*,? \d{4}|\d{1,2} [A-Z][a-z,.]+ \d{4}|[A-Z][a-z]{2}[,.]? \d{4}|'+pattern+r'|\d{1,2}\/\d{4}|\d{4}',x))
df['date'][271] = [df['date'][271][1]]
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
df['date'][461] = re.findall(r'\d{4}',df['date'][461])[0]
df['date'][465] = re.findall(r'\d{4}',df['date'][465])[0]
```

Comment: What codes do you need help with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}|\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{2,4}|[A-Z][a-z]+\-\d{1,2}\-\d{4}|[A-Z][a-z]+[,.]? \d{2}[a-z]*,? \d{4}|\d{1,2} [A-Z][a-z,.]+ \d{4}|[A-Z][a-z]{2}[,.]? \d{4}|'+pattern+r'|\d{1,2}\/\d{4}|\d{4}` is a date matching regex.

Basic Regex:

1. `\d` represents a number in the range `[0-9]`
2. `{1, 2}` is a quantifier, which is a way of saying, match if the previous element is repeated between 1 to 2 times
3. `|` is a boolean or
4. `\` is an escape character, which will match the following character as is; which means `\\` will match if a backslash is present
5. `[a-z]` and `[A-Z]` will match if a character is found
6. `+` is a quantifier similar to `{}`, it matches if the previous string is repeated one or more times
7. `?` quantifier matches if the previous string is repeated 0 or 1 time

When broken down:

1. `\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}` means match if a number is repeated once or twice, followed by a forward slash, followed by 1-2 digits, followed by a forward slash followed by 2-4 numbers. This is intended to catch dates in the form of dd/mm/yyyy or dd/mm/yy or d/m/yyyy or d/m/yy or similar cases
2. `\d{1,2}\-\d{1,2}\-\d{2,4}` is similar to above, but will catch dates in the form of dd-mm-yyyy
3. `[A-Z][a-z]+\-\d{1,2}\-\d{4}` will match dates in the form of Jan-01-2001

Additional tools:

- To learn basic regex, I would strongly recommend [this](https://regexone.com/) resource, it is simple, interactive and doesn't take a lot of time.
- To understand what each component of the regex interprets to, use [this](https://regex101.com/) wonderful tool